# What does velocity relative to CMB mean?

Tags: cosmology, reference-frames, relativity, cosmic-microwave-background, aether

I've see some velocities [such as that of the Sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun) quoted as "relative to the cosmic microwave background"?

How is this different to measuring velocities relative to that old, discredited idea, the ether?

Comment: Well, that is just about the most mind-blowing thing I've read in a while.

Comment: @spraff But isn't learning physics always mindblowing? :P